# Lattice Diamond — How to identify which parts of design take most of FPGA resources?

Tags: fpga, optimization, lattice

I have a Lattice FPGA-targeted design which already takes approximately 95% of the SLICEs available on the device; pretty close to the chip capacity. Unfortunately, I need to add some more logic to it, so I have to optimize things a bit. But how do I identify the most problematic parts of the design? Neither “Network Analyzer” nor “NCD View” tool can give me such data. The best thing I found so far is to filter the NCD View list against a specific module name and manually count all the cells it shows. I believe there must be a better way.

Did I overlook some obvious option or dialog?
Can Lattice Diamond generate a detailed report on device utilization?

Related question (specific to the Xilinx software):
[How to identify areas of a FPGA design that use the most resources and area?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93925)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mostlikely looking for the "Hierarchy – Post Synthesis Resources" view. In my version it is "hidden" as a tab next to the "File List" and "Process" views.

Comment: Thank you, I really overlooked that window. Unfortunately, it won't show anything useful if the project contains even a single line of SystemVerilog code (“No Hierarchy could be parsed out because there is System Verilog in project”).

Comment: oh that is an interesting information I was not aware of. Good to know!